# Oops Concept regarding polymophism

Tags: java, oop

Why to use abstraction when same work is done by method overloading?Take an example of finding area of triangle and area of square It is done by both then whats the use of both in doing same work?

Comment: `"Why to use abstraction when same work is done by method overloading?"` - I can't even begin to describe how wrong this is.  Method overloading and object polymorphism are not even close to the same thing.  Your question makes no sense to me.  All I can really suggest is that you study these concepts further and learn more about object oriented design.  Because you seem to be fundamentally misunderstanding the concepts.

Comment: By "abstraction", do you mean "inheritance"? Inheritance-based polymorphism (subtyping) and ad-hoc polymorphism (overloading) are different kinds of polymorphism. Abstraction is a concept independent from both.

Comment: You even showed a perfect example for polymophysm by inheritance with three potential classes. One abstract class `Shape` with a potential abstract method `area` and two classes inheriting from `Shape` -> `Triangle`, `Square`. Every Shape can have it´s area calculated, but these are different for each inheriting Shape, like it is the case with a `Triangle` and a `Square`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymorphism is the fact that an instance of a class is in same time an instance of its parent class.

So if you have these classes : Shape, Rectangle (extends Shape) and Square (extends Shape), you can put in a List rectangles and squares.

Method oveloading is used to define a different behaviour of subclass from its parent.